# Stop Visual Studio Design mode from refreshing

Tags: visual-studio, refresh

Does anyone know how to stop Visual Studio from automatically refreshing the Design view everytime I modify the source file associated with a Form?

I'm updating strings on a form that has about a million controls.  I'm constantly going back and forth between the design and code for a form.  The load time it takes to render the design each time is killing me.  I'm not changing anything that would directly affect the design view, so is there a way to stop it updating every time?

Comment: If you're changing strings, then you're changing something that would affect design mode. What do you mean?

Comment: It definitely affects design mode, but I don't want to actually see the changes in design mode unless I manually tell it to update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is not.  This is the default behavior and it cannot be changed.  The design view when focused will always try to update with the latest version of the source.  If it has changed the design view will too.  This is necessary to ensure that any changes which occur to the UI reflect changes on the current state of the source code.

Comment: Darn, I'm flipping back and forth a lot, and everytime the design takes about 5 seconds to load.  Which is not horrible, but I need to finish a work assignment tonight that will probably require me to flip back and forth about 300 times. :(

Comment: Perhaps get a faster computer?  Seems strange that a form would take that long to render, even in design view.

Comment: @Soviut, I wouldn't put much past this machine.  It's running a core2duo, 2gig of ram, but it's had the same install of windows XP on it for over 2 years.  2 YEARS!!!  I'm impressed it's still somewhat usable.

Answer (score 2):

My workaround was to edit the code in notepad so I could click around in Design view without refreshes, then pasted the code back into V-Studio